# How to detect changes in form and set new state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, client-side

I have HTML form with set of elements(inputs).

So, how to detect changes in any input and set new statement in object `var data`?

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="parameter" value="30">
```

When I make chnages in input I need to get output object `data` as:

```
var = data = ["paraeter" : 30];
```

Answer (score 0):

> for watch the value on change in angular you should use `ng-change` and `ng-model`

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []).
controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.info = {
    parameter: 30,
    parameters: {
      children: 40
    }
  };
  
  $scope.callBackIfChange = function(){
    console.log($scope.info); 
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <form>
    <label>empty value</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="info.name" ng-change="callBackIfChange()">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>has default value</label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="info.parameter" ng-change="callBackIfChange()">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>nested</label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="info.parameters.children" ng-change="callBackIfChange()">
  </form>
   <hr>
  <b>output:</b> {{info | json}}
 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but if exists another input above as parent, and how to insert value of input below to object above? I mean nested structure: {parameter:{children:40}}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Jquery code covering your cases (onload and input change) **without hard-coding the name attributes** of inputs tags:

```
var inputValuesObj = {}; // << Your Object

$(document).ready(function() {
    getDefaultInputValues();
});

$(document).on("load keyup", "input", function() {
    getDefaultInputValues();
});

function getDefaultInputValues() {
    $("input").each(function(index) {
        inputValuesObj[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
    });
    $("div#res").html(JSON.stringify(inputValuesObj));
}
```

Your test here - https://jsfiddle.net/uo08fedh/20/

Hope it helps!